# How to fix openacc warning/error about unknown driver

Tags: c++, nvcc, openacc

I try to compile a C++ OpenACC code (unchanged) that was working before my distribution update (from Ubuntu 20 to 22).
And as you could guess, this compilation is not working anymore.
Therefore, I think to the problem is more a setup problem that a code problem.
So now my compiler is: `nvc++ 22.11-0` on Ubuntu 22.04.

The compilation returns the following error message:

```
nvc++-Warning-unknown driver variable assigned on the command line: /home/user/src/file.cpp
nvc++-Warning-No files to process
```

And unfortunately, I found nothing about this error message on the Internet nor in the compiler documentation.

The code is big and I did not manage to create a MWE from it, but simple examples from `nvc++` documentation are working fine (otherwise, it would be too easy to reproduce this error...).

So if you have any idea about how to solve this error, or a comprehension of about what the message means or a test to reproduce the error, I would be glad; because now I fill like blocked in a dead-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as weird as it can seems, the problem was in the path to the file: it contained a `=` character.

`nvc++` is disturbed by such symbol in the path to the file. Nothing to do with the drivers. A misleading error message...

Comment: Thanks, I'm now able to reproduce the warning.  While rare, equal signs are valid symbols for file names, hence I added a problem report, TPR #32883, and sent to our engineers for review.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this once before and it had to do with the order in which the compiler flags were listed on the command line.  I don't remember the details but thought it was specific to the "-ta=tesla:managed" flag and moving this towards the beginning of the command line fixed the issue.

What command line flags are you using and what is the order in which they appear ?

The "-ta" flag is deprecated in favor of the "-gpu" flag.  "-ta" is specific to OpenACC but with nvc++ now also supporting OpenMP target offload and standard language parallelism, we decided to move the GPU specific sub-options under a common flag.  Hence I recommend moving from using "-ta=tesla:managed" to "-acc -gpu=managed".

Comment: For now, to keep it a bit simpler I use only the multi-cpu parallelization. Therefore my command line flags are only `-acc=multicore` (I removed everytning else), and still the same error.

Comment: Very odd.  To be clear, the command line is simply "nvc++ -acc=multicore /home/user/src/file.cpp"?  The warning seems like the source file is being interrupted to be part of the "-acc" flag but I can't reproduce it.  Once our office is open again next week (we're closed for the holiday), I'll ask IT to install Ubuntu 22.04 on a VM.  I would find it very strange that the OS would matter, but it's possible.  In the mean time, if you can provide a minimal reproducing example, that may help.  If I can reproduce the error, I can usually determine the issue, otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was off the grid for few days.
The command has some extra `-I` for include folders. I am trying to remove them on my way to create a minimal reproducing example.